# convergence and divergence test on an exponential function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to test the convergence/divergence of this:

$$\int_0^\infty x \sin(e^x) \, dx $$ by any method

I looked through convergence test and integral test

Comment: This function has an antiderivative that's easy to find, just integrate by parts.

Comment: @DougM : That's not true.  Suppose $f(x) = 1$ for $x$ between $n$ and $n+ 2^{-n}$ for integers $n$.  Then $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges but $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) \ne 0$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Integrating by parts, one gets
$$
\int_0^M x \sin(e^x) \, dx =\left[(xe^{-x})(-\cos (e^x)) \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_0^M+\int_0^M (1-x)e^{-x} \cos(e^x) \, dx
$$ and
$$
\left|\int_0^M (1-x)e^{-x} \cos(e^x) \, dx\right|\leq \int_0^M |1-x|e^{-x} \, dx<\infty
$$ giving the **convergence** of the initial integral.

Answer (score 1):

Outline: Use integration by parts, letting $u=\frac{x}{e^x}$ and $dv=e^x\sin(e^x)\,dx$.

Then $du=(e^{-x}-xe^{-x})\,dx$ and we can take $v=-\cos(e^x)$.

The rest is straightforward, for $uv$ behaves nicely "at $\infty$", and $\int_0^\infty (e^{-x}-xe^{-x})\cos(e^x)\,dx$ converges, because $|\cos(e^x)|\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Make the change of variable $x=\log(y)$; then the integral becomes
$$
I=\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(y)\sin(y)}y \, dy
$$
which converges since $\frac{\log(y)}{y}$ tends monotonically (for $y>e$) to $0$. In fact, 
$$
I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n+\int_1^{\pi}f(y)\,dy,\quad I_n:=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\log(y)\sin(y)}y \, dy
$$
Then the $I_n$ have alternating signs and the monotonicity $I_{n+1}<I_{n}\leq \pi \log(n)/n$ holds definitively.

Comment: How does going monotonically to $0$ prove convergence?  In $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac {dx} x = +\infty$, the function goes monotonically to $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: That was NOT what I meant with my answer. In the previous example we have a positive function tending monotonically to zero (at least definitively)  multiplied by an *oscillating* function, $\sin(y)$. So you are easily reconducted to the case of the series with alternating sign.

Comment: I think this answer would bear some elaboration. $\qquad$

Comment: That's quickly done: split the integral in integrals from $n\pi$ to $(n+1)\pi$. The you obtain an alternating sign series with absolute values tending monotonically to zero. Then apply the well known criterion for series.

Comment: If you spell that out carefully in your answer I'll up-vote it. $\qquad$

Comment: It's just Dirichlet's test.